# gcloud docker not working on Compute Engine VM

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to get docker images from Container Engine to run on a Compute Engine VM. On my laptop I can run `gcloud docker pull gcr.io/projectid/image-tag`

I just spun up a Debian VM on Compute Engine, but when I try to run any `gcloud docker` command I get `ERROR: (gcloud.docker) Docker is not installed.`

```
> gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 140.0.0
alpha 2017.01.17
beta 2017.01.17
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2017.01.17
core-nix 2017.01.17
gcloud 
gsutil 4.22
gsutil-nix 4.22

> gcloud docker --version
ERROR: (gcloud.docker) Docker is not installed.
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker makes it seem like `gcloud docker` should work.

Am I supposed to install docker on the VM before running `gcloud docker`?

Comment: `sudo yum install docker` works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I supposed to install docker on the VM before running gcloud docker?

Yes. The error message is telling you that Docker needs to be installed on the machine for `gcloud docker` to work.

You can either install docker manually on your Debian VM or you can launch a VM that has docker pre-installed onto the machine, such as the [Container-Optimized OS from Google](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/).

Answer (score 4):

Per intuition i tried to install docker with `sudo apt-get install docker`, but I was wrong, the actual docker package name is `docker.io`, so I restarted the process and worked this way:

1. Install the docker package:

`sudo apt-get install docker.io`

1. Test if docker is working

`sudo gcloud docker ps`

1. Pull your image from the image repository, e.g. **gcr.io**. If dont have
   a particular tag use the *latest* one.

`sudo gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/$PROJECT_NAME/$APPLICATION_IMAGE_NAME:latest`

1. Run your image. Remember to specify the port mapping correctly, the first port is the one will be exposed in the GCE instance and the second one is the one exposed internally by the docker container, e.g `EXPOSE 8000`. For instance in the following example my app is configured to work at the `8000` port but it will be accessed by the public on the default www port, the `80`.

`sudo docker run -d -p 80:8000 --name=$APPLICATION_IMAGE_NAME \
    --restart=always gcr.io/$PROJECT_NAME/$APPLICATION_IMAGE_NAME:latest`

The `--restart` flag will allow this container to be restarted every time the instance restarts

I hope it works for you.